# invalidateLater for incrementing values

Tags: r, shiny, invalidation

I have a Shiny app which among other functionalities, allows the user to click on a leaflet map,captue the lat lon as the coordinates of a ship, feed in the course and speed and pass this information on to a radar simulator over a socket. Given the course and speed of the ship,I need to pass on the updated coordinates to the radar simulator every second. Presumably, `invalidateLater()` is what I need after reading through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54364680/increment-reactivevalue-inside-invalidatelater-observer). But somehow I just can't wrap my head around the functioning of `invalidateLater()`. This is what I have unsuccessfully tried so far:

```
#Reactive values to hold the lat lon of the map_click event
rvs <- reactiveValues()
observe({
  req(rvs$own_ship_lat)
  invalidateLater(1000) 

  #Data to be passed to the simulator
  df <- data.frame(Type='Platform',ID='Own_Ship',Lat = rvs$own_ship_lat,
                   Lon = rvs$own_ship_lon,
                   Alt=10.5, LandReflect = 10,
                   Course=input$own_course,
                   Speed=input$own_speed)

  #Convert the data to json format
  jdata <- jsonlite::toJSON(df)

  #Function to make a socket connection and pass on the json data to the simulator
  sendDRS(jdata)

  #Calculate next point to be passed on to the simulator
  next_pt <- geosphere::destPoint(c(rvs$own_ship_lon, rvs$own_ship_lat), 
                       input$own_course, input$own_speed)


    isolate(rvs$own_ship_lat <- next_pt[2])
    isolate(rvs$own_ship_lon <- next_pt[1])
    # print(next_pt)

})
```

`rvs$own_ship_lat` and `rvs$own_ship_lon` hold the lat lon values of the mouseclick on the leaflet map. If I uncomment the the `print(next_pt)`, it infinitely prints the first rightly calculated `next_pt` values.

Comment: Conceptually, what you have here should work. Can you produce a cut-down reproducible example (something we can run to see what you're seeing)? That would help us figure out where it's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not entirely sure how, but finally got it to work by removing the `req()` from `observe`:

```
observe({
    invalidateLater(1000)
    tryCatch({
    isolate(next_pt <- geosphere::destPoint(c(rvs$own_ship_lon, rvs$own_ship_lat),
                                    input$own_course, input$own_speed))
    print(next_pt)
    isolate(rvs$own_ship_lat <- next_pt[2])
    isolate(rvs$own_ship_lon <- next_pt[1])
    },error = function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})

  })
```

Added the `tryCatch()` so that the application does not stop when `rvs$own_ship_lat` or `rvs$own_ship_lon` are not available.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying this a bit so that you have a min reprex to play around with:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput('own_course', 'Set Course', min = 0, max = 359, value = 60),
  sliderInput('own_speed', 'Set Speed', min = 0, max = 40, value = 12),
  leafletOutput('own_ship', height = 600, width = '100%')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #Own ship map
  output$own_ship <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(72.8777,19.076,12) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenSeaMap) %>%
      leafem::addMouseCoordinates()
  })

  rvs <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$own_ship_click, {
    rvs$own_ship_lat <- input$own_ship_click$lat
    rvs$own_ship_lon <- input$own_ship_click$lng
  })

  observe({
    req(rvs$own_ship_lat)
    invalidateLater(1000) 

    #Calculate next point to be passed on to the simulator
    next_pt <- geosphere::destPoint(c(rvs$own_ship_lon, rvs$own_ship_lat), 
                                    input$own_course, input$own_speed)

    print(next_pt)
    isolate(rvs$own_ship_lat <- next_pt[2])
    isolate(rvs$own_ship_lon <- next_pt[1])


  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you run this you will observe that the `print` statement prints the correctly calculated values but not at an interval of one second. Like I mentioned in my question, I need to pass on these values to a simulator, but at an interval of one second. How can I achieve this?